# Dryer vent vertical rise

Tags: dryer, vent

My vent rises vertically about 5 ft from the dryer. I am trying to decide if it will considerably save drying time if I move it to only about a foot above from the dryer exhaust is, as the space both inside and outside the wall is available.

I would invest in it only if the time and energy savings from 5 to 1 ft vertical are significant. I suspect that vertical retains moisture.

The dryer is already pretty fast because it is gas heated, about half the time of the electrical dryer in another unit I own.

Comment: Extremely unlikely that it will make a difference in either time or energy usage.

Comment: [Efficiency Values for Dryer Exhaust Terminations and Fittings](https://dryerbox.com/ratings/dryerfittingschart.htm) – dryerbox.com

Comment: > M1502.6 Duct length.The maximum developed length of a clothes dryer exhaust duct shall not exceed 35 feet from the dryer location to the wall or roof termination. The maximum length of the duct shall be reduced 2.5 feet for each 45-degree (0.8 rad) bend, and 5 feet for each 90-degree (1.6 rad) bend. The maximum length of the exhaust duct does not include the transition duct. – [waypointinspection.com](https://waypointinspection.com/dryer-vent-safety/?fbclid=IwAR3oLN2-kCGVVGMZx4yZUR1CabUMqWfAr30BB1Iig9P0XO_jOjTxavJ_Vzk)

Comment: *developed length* takes no account of orientation afaik.

Comment: Flex duct verses smooth duct may make a difference but with the same numbers of elbows I would not expect to see any change. Reversed a down vote.

Comment: The reason for all the quoted code is so that the exhaust fan in the dryer can push air "easily" all the way.  The ductwork orientation is irrelevant, or at least causes less than a couple percent variation of the perceived back-pressure at the fan.

Comment: In addition, the "electric vs. gas" speed has nothing to do with the heat source and everything to do with the set temperature, the airflow rate, drum size, and so on.